# How implement Live tracking in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like implement a live tracking in the background—even if  app wasn’t the currently active app?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you want to track and what system are you using? Also what all have you tried? Right now we don't have any clue what you are doing.

Comment: I'm trying add location tracking inside  mainactiviity.kotin file and iam  method chennel

Answer (score 0):

Check this awesome blog on how to fetch location when the app is in the background.

https://medium.com/@pierre.sabot/how-to-fetch-user-location-in-background-with-flutter-e3494021bdf5